# Rowwise min() and max() fails for column with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, nan

I am trying to take the rowwise max (and min) of two columns containing dates

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_a' : [date(2015, 1, 1), date(2012, 6, 1),
                               date(2013, 1, 1), date(2016, 6, 1)],
                   'date_b' : [date(2012, 7, 1), date(2013, 1, 1), 
                               date(2014, 3, 1), date(2013, 4, 1)]})

df[['date_a', 'date_b']].max(axis=1)
Out[46]: 
0    2015-01-01
1    2013-01-01
2    2014-03-01
3    2016-06-01
```

as expected. However, if the dataframe contains a single NaN value, the whole operation fails

```
df_nan = pd.DataFrame({'date_a' : [date(2015, 1, 1), date(2012, 6, 1),
                                   np.NaN, date(2016, 6, 1)],
                       'date_b' : [date(2012, 7, 1), date(2013, 1, 1), 
                                   date(2014, 3, 1), date(2013, 4, 1)]})

df_nan[['date_a', 'date_b']].max(axis=1)
Out[49]: 
0   NaN 
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
dtype: float64
```

What is going on here? I was expecting this result

```
0    2015-01-01
1    2013-01-01
2    NaN
3    2016-06-01
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be that the NaN is a NaN; any float seems to cause the same problem. I think the float is triggering conversion of all elements to floats.

Comment: Why aren't you using `pandas` datetime` dtype instead of `object` dtype?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this is a bug. By default, the `numeric_only` argument is set to None and its value is determinedby the (mixed) dtypes. The single float in your DataFrame sets the `numeric_only` flag to True and since you don't have any numeric columns your result is all NaNs. `pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c']}).max(axis=1, numeric_only=True)` also returns all NaNs. And `df_nan.max(axis=1, numeric_only=False)`  raises a TypeError as it supposed to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say the best solution is to use the appropriate `dtype`. Pandas provides a very well integrated `datetime` `dtype`. So note, you are using `object` dtypes...

```
>>> df
       date_a      date_b
0  2015-01-01  2012-07-01
1  2012-06-01  2013-01-01
2         NaN  2014-03-01
3  2016-06-01  2013-04-01
>>> df.dtypes
date_a    object
date_b    object
dtype: object
```

But note, the problem disappears when you use

```
>>> df2 = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
>>> df2
      date_a     date_b
0 2015-01-01 2012-07-01
1 2012-06-01 2013-01-01
2        NaT 2014-03-01
3 2016-06-01 2013-04-01
>>> df2.min(axis=1)
0   2012-07-01
1   2012-06-01
2   2014-03-01
3   2013-04-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 6):

This appears to happen when `date` objects are mixed with floats (such as `NaN`) in columns. By default, the `numeric_only` flag is set because of the single float value. For example, replace your `df_nan` with this:

```
df_float = pd.DataFrame({'date_a' : [date(2015, 1, 1), date(2012, 6, 1),
                                    1.023, date(2016, 6, 1)],
                        'date_b' : [date(2012, 7, 1), 3.14, 
                                    date(2014, 3, 1), date(2013, 4, 1)]})

print(df_float.max(1))

0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
dtype: float64
```

If the flag is manually set to false, this would rightly throw a `TypeError` because:

```
print(date(2015, 1, 1) < 1.0)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-362-ccbf44ddb40a> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 print(date(2015, 1, 1) < 1.0)

TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.date() < float()
```

However, pandas seems to coerce everything to `NaN`. As a workaround, converting to `str` using `df.astype` appears to do it:

```
out = df_nan.astype(str).max(1)
print(out) 
0    2015-01-01
1    2013-01-01
2           nan
3    2016-06-01
dtype: object
```

In this case, sorting lexicographically yields the same solution as before.

Otherwise, as [juan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899340/in-python-rowwise-min-and-max-fails-when-containing-a-nan/45899388#comment78757934_45899340), you can cast to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
out = df_nan.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce').max(1)
print(out)

0   2015-01-01
1   2013-01-01
2   2014-03-01
3   2016-06-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```python
>>> df_nan.where(df_nan.T.notnull().all()).max(axis=1)
Out[1]:
0    2015-01-01
1    2013-01-01
2          None
3    2016-06-01
dtype: object
```

Where:

1. `df_nan.T.notnull().all()` computes a mask of row containing no `np.nan`
2. `df_nan.where()` applies the former mask to the dataframe
3. `.max(axis=1)` gets the row-wise maximum

This works because the maximum of an array where all values are `np.nan` is `None`. It allows to keep track of rows where a value is missing by not showing a maximum.

But this decision is up to you, otherwise the solution of @juanpa.arrivillaga that converts `NaN` to `NaT` is what you want.