# Inserting a datetime.max into a pandas series changes the series type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I create a series from some random dates

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

pd.Series([datetime(2012, 8, 1), datetime(2013, 4, 1), datetime(2013, 8, 1)])
Out[49]: 
0   2012-08-01
1   2013-04-01
2   2013-08-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

However, if I create a series with a `datetime.max`, the dtype of the series is all of a sudden an object

```
pd.Series([datetime(2012, 8, 1), datetime(2013, 4, 1), datetime.max])
Out[50]: 
0           2012-08-01 00:00:00
1           2013-04-01 00:00:00
2    9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999
dtype: object
```

Also the way the dates are shown changes. I guess this latter point is related to the fact that the series is now an object.

`datetime.max` is of the same type as the other dates

```
type(datetime.max)
Out[53]: datetime.datetime

type(datetime(2014, 1,1))
Out[54]: datetime.datetime
```

What is going on here? How can create a series containing the 'max'-datetime value? Like this

```
0   2012-08-01
1   2013-04-01
2   9999-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `datetime64[ns]` dtype can represent dates between [1678 AD and 2262 AD](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units). Since `datetime.max` lies outside this range, the dtype of the Series was changed to `object` and all the values converted to `datetime.datetime`s so that the Series could hold the required range of datetimes.

Currently the nanosecond-frequency `datetime64[ns]` dtype (as opposed to say, `datetime64[s]`, or `datetime64[Y]`) is the [only NumPy datetime dtype that Pandas supports](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7307). The [recommended workaround](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans) is to use `pd.Period` or `pd.PeriodIndex` objects to represent dates outside the range representable by `datetime64[ns]`:

```
import datetime as DT
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([DT.datetime(2012, 8, 1), DT.datetime(2013, 4, 1), DT.datetime.max])
p = s.apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='D'))
print(p)
```

yields

```
0   2012-08-01
1   2013-04-01
2   9999-12-31
dtype: object
```

Notice that the `freq` parameter must be set to something larger than `ns`
to expand the allowable range of dates (at the expense of less granularity).
Here is a [table of common aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) you can use for the `freq` parameter.

Comment: Aha! Thank you. But why is datetime64 chosen as the default type for the other dates.

Comment: Fast, vectorized datetime arithmetic is possible using NumPy `datetime64`s. So its the preferred dtype for Pandas NDFrame's datetime values.

Comment: Is there a way to force it to choose plain `datetime`? I am aware of `date` but that has some other problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899340/in-python-rowwise-min-and-max-fails-when-containing-a-nan

Comment: Pandas automatically converts Series or DataFrames containing `datetime.datetime` to the NumPy `datetime64[ns]` dtype -- when possible. Unfortunately the only way I know to prevent the conversion is to do as you did above -- stick in an object like `datetime.max` which can not be converted to a `datetime64[ns]`.